# Increasing width for an inline form input?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
           <form class="form-inline">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only"></label>
                   <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only"></label>
                   <input class="form-control hello" type="text"/>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only"></label>
                   <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
               </div>
               <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit"/>
           </form>
```

How would I make the middle input have a width of 500px? I tried wrapping it in a row with `col-xs-10`, but that also didn't work. Here is a [jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uvdU8/)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working correctly. Each input with the "hello" class is 500px wide. What is going wrong for you?

Comment: @showdev Try expanding the window

Comment: Ah yes. Bootstrap overrides your style with `width:auto`. You'll just need to make your CSS more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than bootstrap's: `.form-inline .hello { width:500px; }`. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/uvdU8/4/).

Comment: @showdev The width doesn't change. If you change it to `width: 1000px` the width of the input stays the same.

Comment: You just need to update your CSS at the breakpoints to override bootstrap. Be careful though, because you don't want it to break the viewport of the device.

Comment: @showdev Can you make an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: KevinBowersox and ThomasMcNaught have provided working solutions. Both seem to use CSS with greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than bootstrap's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS rule would work:

```
.form-inline .form-control.hello {
    display: inline-block;
    width:500px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uvdU8/3/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to add `style="width:500px;"` to the input.

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMcNaught/uvdU8/1/

If you want it to be applied through CSS then try an ID.

```
input#width {
    width: 500px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMcNaught/uvdU8/2/